# How to add this background-image effect to a div?

Tags: css, background-image

I need to add the following detail image to each div of a certain class on my page.

[image: stack of papers detail]

In the wireframes, it looks like this:

[image: wireframe image]

I can't just use the above image entirely because the white space can be variable heights. How would I achieve this using the background image property in CSS? Everything I've tried so far doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Some code/explanation on what you have tried would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `:after` combined with absolute positioning.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ChJnr/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    width: 250px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    padding: 16px;
}
.box:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
    right: 16px;
    bottom: -16px;
    background: url(http://dummyimage.com/250x16/f0f/fff);
    height: 16px;
}
```

If you need this to work in older browsers, you could instead [add a harmless little `span`](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ChJnr/5/) to replace the use of `:after`.

Comment: Does not work if the image has a transparent background however, as it adds a `#ccc` background to it.

Comment: This looks promising! I'm going to try this out tonight and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @Charlie: You're exactly right, and I've already resolved the problem.

Comment: This is very close to what I need! However, I want the edges of the box:after image to line up with the div it's under. Right now, the top box always has extra width on the sides. I've played with the padding, but that just seems to mess it up. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: @ellenchristine: Did you try changing the `left`/`right` properties to `0`? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ChJnr/7/

Answer (score 2):

**2 Options:**

*Option 1:* You make 3 divs which would look something like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">Stuff</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Since you are using a transparent image for your bottom image, you need to make sure you don't set a background-color to the container div, instead set it to the content div.

*Option 2:* Use CSS3 border-image property.

The one drawback to this is that the image you are using for the bottom border has to have the same color background as the background of whatever div it's on top of. Example:

With transparent background: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/k9uyx/

This also requires the browser supports CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

```
.someClass {
    backgroung-image: url('path-to-image-form-css-file');
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: ...
}
```

Comment: The only thing is that I need the boxes to have variable heights.

Comment: $('.someClass').css('height',anyCorrectValue);

Answer (score 0):

Make it into 3 divs - One to contain the entire "original" div, one div that floats to the bottom of the container div to hold the bottom image, and one to contain everything else.

Comment: Yikes. Is this the only way to make this work? Isn't there any way to nudge the background image out past the image itself? I know that seems like it obviously wouldn't, but I was thinking with negative margins or something it could work.

Comment: If you aren't already using the padding and border properties of the div in any meaningful way, and depending on the context of the div in the page, you might be able to do that using the background-origin property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-origin.asp

Comment: More specifically, set the background-origin to border-box instead of content-box and keep everything else inside the content box... Not sure if this works for your particular case without any other code for context, though.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create a class like that. It's a guess, but I believe this should work OK:

```
.someClass {
    background: #FFF url('path') no-repeat center bottom;
    width: 175px;
}
```